# How can I query .local bonjour DNS entries?

Tags: dns, bonjour, mdns

It's pretty straightforward to query out the guts of a DNS-SD entry via `dig` by asking your nameserver directly; but for multicast DNS, I'm not sure where to look.

Edit: My motivation is to be able to see example DNS entries so that I can better configure static bonjour entries for my OS X machines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main utility is `dns-sd`, e.g.:

```
% dns-sd -B _afpovertcp._tcp
Browsing for _afpovertcp._tcp
Timestamp     A/R Flags if Domain           Service Type              Instance Name
20:02:23.350  Add     2  4 local.           _afpovertcp._tcp.         myhost
```

Comment: Does that have any tricks for getting at the underlying entries (or verbose details?) - part of my motivation is to figure out what entries a given service registers.  (for instance, the afp shares also have an associated _device-info._tcp)

Comment: When I tried it the command hangs... man page: "The dns-sd command is primarily intended for interactive use.  Because its command-line arguments and output format are subject to change, invoking it from a shell script will generally be fragile. Additionally, the asynchronous nature of DNS Service Discovery does not lend itself easily to script-oriented programming. For example, calls like "browse" never complete; the action of performing a "browse" sets in motion machinery to notify the client whenever instances of that service type appear or disappear from the network."

Comment: @KurtHarriger it's not "hung", it sits there continuously waiting for further multicast transmissions from other hosts.

Comment: Yes, I get that.  I was looking for something suitable to use from a shell script.  While it answered the readers question, I thought it worth noting this limitation so that others users like myself are aware of it.

Answer (score 13):

Aha, the secret is the multicast address/port.

For example, to query available AFP servers:

```
dig @224.0.0.251 -p 5353 -t ptr _afpovertcp._tcp.local
```

Comment: This works for services on the same machine, but does not show services from other devices in the network. On the other hand, Bonjour Browser does show all services.

Comment: Unfortunately, this looks llke it no longer works with versions of dig newer than 9.18: https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/issues/3428