# Bonjour local host names in Android

Tags: android, bonjour

How can I make an Android network request lookup a local domain name registered with Bonjour?

I get this error when trying to fetch data using Volley.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "xxxxx.local": No address associated with hostname
```

Comment: Basically "Unable to resolve host" means DNS lookup has failed. Can you access xxxxx.local in a browser (or ping in a shell)?

Comment: On iOS, macOS and windows I can. On Android I cannot.

Comment: Maybe related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49188/how-to-get-mdns-working-for-chrome-on-android https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/faq.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588074/how-can-i-query-local-bonjour-dns-entries

Comment: Haven't tried yet but DNS-SD seems to be a key word to resolve it, as Bonjour uses mDNS. https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html

Answer (score 0):

If you control the whole network stack, you can perform DNS service discovery (DNS-SD) through Android's NsdManager. I recommend this guide from the documentation:

> https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd

In short, it boils down to:

```
mNsdManager.discoverServices(
    SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);
```

You can cross-reference the service you wish to resolve to by inspecting the response from `dns-sd` on Mac:

```
$ dns-sd -Z . .
_http._tcp                                      PTR     myserver._http._tcp
myserver._http._tcp                             SRV     0 0 80 myserver.local. ; Replace with unicast FQDN of target host
myserver._http._tcp                             TXT     ""
```

In the NsdManager.DiscoveryListener callback, you can obtain the corresponding IP address from `NsdServiceInfo.getHost()`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with the IP of localhost ? 127.0.0.1 or 10.0.2.2:80 ?

Comment: IP works, but not practical for what I'm trying to do. I need to use the hostname, but would be fine to make a lookup to get the IP and then do the network request.

Comment: InetAddress.getByName("...") does not work. Thanks for the article though!

Comment: Downvoted because the question is explicitly about looking up Bonjour hostnames.